# mongodb Can't use $and with String

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am not an expert with mongodb so I am tackling a searching issue using regex.

My document called Post is structured like this :

```
{
  _id : String,
  keywords : [{
    timesFound : Number,
    keyword : String
  }]
}
```

As input I have an array of potential keywords, eg: ["apple","orange"].
How can I search all documents that match /apple/i AND /orange/i ?

I have tried a query like this :

```
{"keywords.keyword" : $and: [{$regex: /apple/i}, {$regex: /orange/i}]}}
```

but got this error "Can't use $and with String."

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) should be a top level operator, try:

```
Post.find({ $and: [ { "keywords.keyword": {$regex: /apple/i} }, { "keywords.keyword": {$regex: /orange/i} } ] })
```

Comment: what if you have $and operator within another $and operator. I am getting the same error but have many nested $and operators.

Comment: Can be nested like: `{ $and: [ { $and: [...] }, {  $or: [...] }] }`

Comment: I wasn't using $and as the top level operator inside the array with more $and operators. This was causing the problem. Thanks a lot.